# Chromium/Chrome tabs crashes on Ubuntu/Edubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason the tabs of Chromium and Chrome have started to crash (He's dead Jim) when running on Ubuntu or Edubuntu 12.04.3. It seems to happen only when I log in. I tried the browsers on Ubuntu 13.10 and everything worked fine.

Any suggestions?

Ps. The browser doesn't crash, just the tabs, and I can open new ones (but they also crash after a while).

Here's the output command `free` on the terminal after a tab crash:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2041116    1722740     318376          0       2868     267256
-/+ buffers/cache:    1452616     588500
Swap:      2085884        104    2085780
```

Compared to the output before the crash:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2041116    1967108      74008          0      14632     253036
-/+ buffers/cache:    1699440     341676
Swap:      2085884         40    2085844
```

Comment: It seems like a memory issue. Next time when your browser's tab crash. Open terminal parallel (without closing the browser) and run this command: `free`. post the output in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Output from Terminal now added to original post!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the issue with the tabs crashing after logging in, however, I used to have issues running tabs on Chrome Ubuntu 12.04. I found this typically happened while watching a video in one tab, with more than one tab open and a program or two open. Sometimes, I needed this for school, so it was inevitable. When watching videos or using programs for personal use, I stopped multitasking and that kept the tabs from crashing most times.

This issue is not specific to Ubuntu - I also used Win 7 computers at school which had the same issue. Again, this is with multiple tabs open (usually one running video) and one or more programs in addition to Chrome open.

I believe that issue is a hardware one - too small a processor for everything that's running. I was using a very small net-book with out a lot of power or memory. If these tabs are ones that you have opening on startup, you may want to disable that (disabling applications from opening upon log - in is one of the first things articles/blogs will suggest to speed up Ubuntu).

Hope that helps!